# Titanium Appcelerator callback fuction not working in Android

Tags: javascript, callback, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-android

I have working in Titanium Appcelerator , Both iOS and Android .
The calll Back Function Not workig in Android But work in iOS, Below is simple example

```
$.saveBtnVw.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log("Save Button Clicked");
    saveAction(calBkFun);
});

var calBkFun = function(){
    console.log("Inside Call Back Function");
    alert("Call Back function Working.....");
};

function saveAction(calBkFun){
    console.log("Inside SaveAction Function");
    calBkFun;
}
```

Only get console Output **"Sav e Button Clicked"** And **"Save Button Clicked" .**

But not getin **"Inside Call Back Function"** and also not getting alert.

That's also not working for my common function(like inside app.js).
Hope Some one will Help to solve this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

calBkFun is a function so you should call it like this :

```
function saveAction(calBkFun){
    console.log("Inside SaveAction Function");
    calBkFun();
}
```